# The method save(User) is undefined for the type UserRepositoryTests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have just started learning and experimenting with spring-boot and hibernate and there is this problem I can't seem to figure out.

```
package net.codejava;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.Rollback;

@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = Replace.NONE)
@Rollback(false)


public class UserRepositoryTests {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepositoryTests repo;
    
    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;
    
    @Test
    public void testCreateUser() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail("xyz@gmail.com");
        user.setPassword("XYZ!@#");
        user.setFirstname("XYZ");
        user.setLastname("PQR");
        user.setUsername("XZY");
         
        User savedUser = repo.save(user);  
        User existUser = entityManager.find(User.class, savedUser.getIdUser());      
        assertThat(user.getEmail()).isEqualTo(existUser.getEmail());
         
    }


}
```

There is some error with line 38 (i.e,User savedUser = repo.save(user);)
is says that"The method save(User) is undefined for the type UserRepositoryTests"

[image]

User.java

```
package net.codejava;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idUser;
    
    @Column(nullable = false,unique=true,length = 45)
    private String email;
    
    @Column(nullable = false,unique=true,length = 45)
    private String firstname;
    
    @Column(nullable = false,unique=true,length = 45)
    private String lastname;
    
    @Column(nullable = false,unique=true,length = 45)
    private String username;
    
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String IPaddress;
    
    @Column(nullable = false,length = 64)
    private String password;
    
    
    public Long getIdUser() {
        return idUser;
    }
    public void setIdUser(Long idUser) {
        this.idUser = idUser;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getIPaddress() {
        return IPaddress;
    }
    public void setIPaddress(String iPaddress) {
        IPaddress = iPaddress;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
package net.codejava;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

Please let me know what to do.

Comment: What is inside your second 'src' folder? You have another src folder just above your 'target' folder.

Comment: I believe you wanted to autowire the UserRepository interface but instead autowired UserRepositoryTests class. And as the error states clearly there is no save method defined for UserRepositoryTests class.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem exactly!  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

the problem was UserRepositoryTests it should have been UserRepository.